# Enabling a button based on textBox and radiobutton

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently working on a homework assignment where I need to set up a calculator-type program. It needs to read one or two user-input values (depending on the calculation), and then perform the calculation based on the values.

I currently have

- 2 textBoxes (`tbInput1` and `tbInput2`),
- 4 radioButtons,
- one button (`btnCalc`)
- a blank `label` in which the result will be displayed.

Two of the radioButtons (`rbtnTrap` and `rbtnFak`) disable the first textBox when checked; the other two need two values to be entered, and for that reason enable both textBoxes when checked. `btnCalc` is supposed to enable itself when the relevant number of textBoxes have value - the relevant number of textBoxes depends on which radio button is checked.

The problem is that when I check `rbtnTrap` or `rbtnFak` (disabling `tbInput1`) and enter an integer in `tbInput2`, `btnCalc` stays disabled.

I'll try to explain what I have so far:

- In the `_TextChanged` event for `tbInput1`, I have an exact copy of the second `if` block posted below. `tbInput1` is only active when `rbtnPot` OR `rbtnFib` are checked, so that control only runs when that is the case.
- In the `_TextChanged` event for `tbInput2`, I have the below, since `tbInput2` is **always** enabled, and the control must run no matter which radio button is checked, although the control should run differently if i check `rbtnTrap` OR `rbtnFak` as opposed to `rbtnPot` OR `rbtnFib`.

Or that's my understanding of it. I'm certainly open to suggestions and corrections.

```
private void tbInput2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //For single-field values
    if ((rbtnTrap.Checked || rbtnFak.Checked) && 
        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.tbInput2.Text))
    {
        btnCalc.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        btnCalc.Enabled = false;
    }
    // For multi-field values
    if ((rbtnPot.Checked || rbtnFib.Checked) && 
        (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.tbInput1.Text)
        && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.tbInput2.Text)))
    {
        btnCalc.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        btnCalc.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is a homework, I am not going to give your the straight answer, but instead a hint: the problem is in the code of the `tbInput2_TextChanged` event (code that you posted).

When `rbtnTrap` or `rbtnFak` are checked, your code will be run following such a path you don't think it will. Set a breakpoint (<kbd>F9</kbd>) on the first line of the `tbInput2_TextChanged` code and run the code step by step (<kbd>F10</kbd>) after entering some text in `tbInput2`.
You will see why your button `btnCalc` is enabled as you think it is, **but disabled in the next moment**.

Feel free to comment if you need more help afterwards. :)

---

**EDIT**

The problem comes from your `if` blocks. When one of `rbtnTrap` and `rbtnFak` is checked:

- your code will run in the `if` clause of the first block and then do `btnCalc.Enabled = true;` but...
- it will also run in the `else` clause of the second block (because `(rbtnPot.Checked || rbtnFib.Checked)` is false) and thus do `btnCalc.Enabled = false;`.

Comment: Aha! Well, I can definitely see why disposing a !=null component would re-disable the button. I am rather unsure of where it comes from, though, because I must have set the program to do it somehow. Any hints on that? (And no straight answers is perfectly fine. I want to learn - not copy/paste. :))

Comment: I'm not sure why you are talking about "*disposing a !=null component*". Are you using the "disposing" term as in `someObject.Dispose()`? (See my edit for your problem)

Comment: Ah, sorry. Once I finished running through the problem with F10, it took me to the designer.cs file. First thing I saw there was `protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)` and beneath that `if (disposing && (components != null))`. Obviously not what you meant. Thanks for the edit and the tips. I'll see about tweaking my code to stop checking after the right clause. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much I understand your problem (I'm sorry, the explanation was a bit all over the place), but one thing that I do see, is that you're only implementing your tests in one event when you have two controls to check.

It sounds like a simple problem, but I really can't understand what is implemented where and who is supposed to do what, so if my 2 cents above were useless and you can explain the question again, that'll probably help in finding a solution

Comment: No problem! Edited for clarity - I hope. Hopefully my ramblings make more sense now. :)